# Margins set by pixels are inconsistent between Firefox, Chrome and IE8

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, margin, sass

In this case, IE8 and Chrome look the same, but Firefox displays something different:

In Firefox:

[image]

In Internet Explorer 8:

[image]

In Google Chrome:

[image]

Why do the last two have a very slim separation?

Here's the HTML:

```
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "OurApproach")">OUR APPROACH</a></li>
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Menu")">MENU</a></li>
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Contact")">GET IN TOUCH</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Here's the CSS, (using SCSS):

```
/* The inconsistency is in the margin-top rule of the UL. */
#navigation { /* This is just a UL element. I used the margin-top, to position it. */
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: -16px;
    margin-top: 117px;

    li {
        background-color: #934B00;
        @include nav-radius;
        color: White;
        float: left;
        font-size: 14px;
        margin-right: 6px;
        padding: 5px;
        cursor:pointer;

         a { text-decoration:none; color:White; }
         a:hover { text-decoration:none; color:#904E00;}
         a:visited { text-decoration:none; color:White; }
         a:link { text-decoration:none; color:White; }
    }

    li:hover {
        color:#904E00;
        background-color:#EEA74F;
    }
}
```

Comment: IN IE8, press F-12 and see if you're in STANDARDS or QUIRKS mode. If you're in QUIRKS mode, you have the wrong doctype declaration.

Comment: I don't know, but that's the way it always is...

Comment: `Document Mode: IE8 Standards` - There ya go, so I know it's set correctly. Problem still persists, why the downvote to the question?

Comment: I need to get my glasses checked.  I don't see a difference between those three images.

Comment: You cannot nest CSS declarations like that.

Comment: @MattGrande: Check the slim separation in the bottom of each "pill".

Comment: @Diodeus: Yes you can with SCSS.

Comment: Matt: there is a one pixel difference.

Comment: I upvoted to clear the downvote. No idea why the down.

Comment: Showing only the CSS gives us nothing to work with to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a line-height issue, actually - and considering normalize.css doesn't reset that for `<li>`, it might be.

Try:

```
line-height: 1;
```

... and play around with it a bit to see if it makes any difference.

(**Update:** Rewrote entire answer, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try - first - you need to be sure the [Sass CSS extension library](http://nex-3.com/posts/96-scss-sass-is-a-css-extension) isn't the problem so test without it.

Secondly - use Firebug in Firefox and Chrome's equivalent ([Firebug light or something along those lines](http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/chrome/)) to inspect the elements. [Using the HTML inspector and Layout tab](http://getfirebug.com/layout), you should be able to see *exactly* how those elements are being styled/rendered.

Lastly, if you aren't already, use a CSS reset stylesheet to ensure all browsers play nice. [Good discussion of the best reset sheets here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset).

Comment: I'm using Normalize.css and so far following your troubleshooting suggestions nothing comes up as the apparent issue. Basically it's boiling down to Firefox using pixels N and IE/Chrome using pixels N+1 (*so to speak*). :S